# How do I create a column with certain conditions built in (not the same as a conditional column) in python

Tags: python, function, loops, conditional-statements

I've attached a screenshot of a table in excel, but I'm doing this in python[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ct0u.png)

I'm trying to recreate the column "predict" in python, I have the other columns already. I am trying to get the first row of "predict" to be equal to the first row of "ytd" and then for every value following that one, I want it to be the result of the "nc" value multiplied by the previous value in the "predict" column. It doesn't have to be done in this particular order or in this way, I just want that to be the end result, and any clear help to achieve that would be much appreciated. I feel like there should be a way to do this with conditionals, but I am struggling to find the right combination of information.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got any code in Python? Is the information there or are you reading the information from the excel file, and then printing out or saving to the file? I didn't quite understand the question.

Comment: There is no code, I am asking for what code to use to get to my solution. I have the data frame in python as depicted in the screenshot, just without the predict column